# Multiple Value Converter on TextView using MVVMCROSS

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have being struggling in using two value converter on single TextView

Basically I wanted to format the text and change the TextColor based on certain value.

Below is how I am trying to achieve this.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myCustomId"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_color"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        local:MvxBind="Text DateValue, Converter=FormatDate; TextColor Flag, Converter=StatusToColor" />
```

The following are my two converters

```
public class FormatDateValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<DateTime, string>
    {
        protected override string Convert(DateTime value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {            
            //code for formatting date    
            return FormattedDate;
        }
    }
```

==========================

```
public class StatusToColorValueConverter : MvxColorValueConverter
    {
        protected override Cirrious.CrossCore.UI.MvxColor Convert(object value, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Cirrious.CrossCore.UI.MvxColor _Color;
            switch ((int)value)
            {
                case 1:
                    _Color = new Cirrious.CrossCore.UI.MvxColor(93, 210, 85, 1);//green
                    break;
                case 2:
                    _Color = new Cirrious.CrossCore.UI.MvxColor(255, 210, 0, 1);//red
                    break;

                case 3:
                    _Color = new Cirrious.CrossCore.UI.MvxColor(208, 14, 13, 1);//yellow
                    break;
                default:
                    _Color = new Cirrious.CrossCore.UI.MvxColor(208, 14, 13, 150);//some color
                    break;
            }
            return _Color;
        }
    }
```

Both the converters are getting called but I am not getting any value inside the text view.

can any one please guide to solve this.

Thanks
Aaman

============================
Following is the stack trace for the same

```
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning: 17.34 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 17.34 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
10-09 19:04:08.972 I/mono-stdout(19422): MvxBind:Warning: 17.34 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning: 17.36 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 17.36 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
10-09 19:04:09.002 I/mono-stdout(19422): MvxBind:Warning: 17.36 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning: 17.38 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 17.38 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
10-09 19:04:09.012 I/mono-stdout(19422): MvxBind:Warning: 17.38 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning: 17.39 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 17.39 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
10-09 19:04:09.032 I/mono-stdout(19422): MvxBind:Warning: 17.39 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning: 17.40 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 17.40 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
10-09 19:04:09.042 I/mono-stdout(19422): MvxBind:Warning: 17.40 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning: 17.42 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 17.42 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
10-09 19:04:09.052 I/mono-stdout(19422): MvxBind:Warning: 17.42 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
```

Comment: There's a working TextColor sample in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ValueConversion/ValueConversion.UI.Droid/Resources/Layout/View_Colors.axml - maybe try your value converters in that project and see if they work there?

Comment: Hello Stuart, Thanks for your reply I have already seen the example mentioned in the link. Followed the same except the text value is in datetime for dateformat converter and value is in int for statustocolor converter...both are getting called but no value is being displayed

Comment: You don't show the "code for formatting date". Are you sure the FormattedDate variable is correct?

Comment: I'd you have a sample that you can see working and a sample that doesn't work - then see if you can spot the difference... I can't see any difference from the partial info posted here. Also check trace - that often lists useful output.

Comment: Hello Stuart, Getting message as MvxBind:Warning:110.77 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue.

Like to share how I have achieved in case any one else require.

I have simple changed the StatusToColorValueConverter Like below to make it working

```
public class StatusToColorValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<int,Color>
    {            
        protected override Color Convert(int value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Color TextColor = Color.Gray;
            switch ((int)value)
            {
                case 1:
                    TextColor = Color.Green;//green
                    break;
                case 2:
                    TextColor = Color.Yellow;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    TextColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                default:
                    TextColor = Color.Gray;
                    break;
            }
            return TextColor;
        }
    }
```

Note: Color is Android.Graphics.Color class

Now, Simply Call on the TextView

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myCustomId"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_color"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        local:MvxBind="Text DateValue, Converter=FormatDate; TextColor Flag, Converter=StatusToColor" />
```